# react-day-picker: change arial-label attribute

Tags: javascript, accessibility, react-day-picker

The current aria-label format for the react-day-picker is

```
  aria-label="Sun Oct 29 2017"
```

but how to change it to different format like

```
  aria-label="29, OCTOBER SUNDAY 2017"
```

reading through the documentation couldnt help in finding out whether this can be customized

Comment: resolved it formatDay (d: date, locale: String) ⇒ String
Format the string used as aria-label for the given day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the `formatDay` function:

http://react-day-picker.js.org/api/LocaleUtils

to return the string you prefer, e.g.:

```
import DayPicker, { LocaleUtils } from "react-day-picker";

function formatDay(d, locale) {
    return <span>{d.getDate()}-s{d.getMonth()}-{d.getFullYear()}</span>
}

<DayPicker localeUtils={ { ...LocaleUtils, formatDay } } />
```

Comment: Not working now, above link is not accessible now with the latest version, any help with it?

Comment: Please see "Advanced localization" example on https://react-day-picker-v7.netlify.app/docs/localization